# python class get member addressee?

Tags: python, list, class, pyqt

everyone

I used c++ program for a long time.

This days, I make a GUI program using python.

But, I don't understand about class of python.

The problem is like this.

At this Gui program, user can add many view. then click the button to change the view.

In my code. I put the element to a class like this

```
class LoadingView():
    def __init__(self):
        self.idx=0
        self.view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.w1 = self.view.addPlot()
        self.view.nextRow()
        self.w2 = self.view.addPlot()
        self.view.nextRow()
        self.w3 = self.view.addPlot()
        self.view.nextRow()
        self.w4 = self.view.addPlot()
```

and I creat class instant and put it to array

```
        self.TreeIdx = self.TreeIdx + 1
        self.AddNodeToTree(SetDlg.EditBoxName.text())
        Loding_view = LoadingView()
        self.LView.append(LoadingView)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(Loding_view.view, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

finally, when I push button, I want to implement to change the view

```
            self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.LView[int(Text.split('.')[0]) - 1].view, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

but, it returned AttributeError: class LoadingView has no attribute 'view'
I don't know how to implement it . need you help...
thank you!

Comment: You added `LoadingView` instead of `Loding_view`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to include 'view' in your __ init __ function. Right now you only have self.

Try this:

```
class LoadingView:
    def __init__(self,
                 idx=None,
                 view=None,
                 w1=None,
                 w2=None,
                 w3=None,
                 w4=None,
                 Nrows=None,
                 ):
        self.idx=idx if idx is not None else 0
        self.view=view if view is not None else pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.w1=w1
        self.w2=w2
        self.w3=w3
        self.w4=w4
        self.Nrows=Nrows

    def datafill(self):
        for i in self.Nrows:
            self.__dict__['w'+str(i+1)]=self.view.addPlot()

Loading_view=LoadingView()
Loading_view.datafill()
```

You can make w a list instead of explicitly defined terms but the way I've shown will loop over the explicitly defined terms using a dictionary. This method also sets the default value of view and idx should you not provide those when you define an instance of the class.

Comment: Passing it into the constructor is not the problem here. See @BrenBarn's comment.

Comment: Don't flag me for correcting your incorrect answer.

Comment: I didn't flag anyone. I see what you mean.